# How to explain the value of y-axis in Partial Dependency plot

Tags: r, random-forest, partial-plot

sample numbers = n
number of classes = 2
The function is $$F(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^nf(x,x_{ic}) $$
where
$$f(x,x_{ic}) = \log p_1(x,x_{ic}) - \frac{(\log p_1( x,x_{ic} )+\log p_2( x,x_{ic}))}{2}$$

[image]

In the image, as x = 0.25, y is about 0.78.
How to I explain the value 0.78
Thanks in advance for your help.